# How do I structure if-statements for maintainability?

Tags: python, if-statement, structure

I have a package for a very specific purpose that is imported into many other systems and it consists of a *lot* of `if` statements. Is there a way of rewriting the code so that it can be imported into an additional system with slightly different requirements (all additions to the list of `if` statements) while maintaining backwards compatibility?

Vastly simplified current version:

```py
def analyze(result):
    a, b, c, d = result
    value = ''
   
    if a > 50:
        value += 'Y'
    else:
        value += 'N'

    if a == 1 and b == 1 and c == 1 and d == 1:
        value += '1'
    elif a == 2 and b == 1 and c == 1:
        value += 'A'
    elif a == 1 and b == 1 and c == 1:
        value += '2'

    ...

    if d > 100:
        value += '24'
    else:
        value += '0'
    

    return value
```

There's no particular logic to the return values.

Desired functionality:

```py
def analyze(result):
    a, b, c, d = result
   
    if a > 50:
        value += 'Y'
    elif a > 25 and b > 50:                              # new line added here
        value += 'X'                                     # new line added here
    else:
        value += 'N'

    if a == 1 and b == 1 and c == 1 and d == 1:
        value += '1'
    elif a == 2 and b == 1 and c == 1:
        value += 'A'
    elif a == 1 and b == 1 and c == 1:
        value += '2'

    elif a == -1 and b == -1 and c == -1 and d == -1:    # new line added here
        value += 'False'                                 # new line added here
    elif a == -2 and b == -2 and c == -2 and d == -2:    # new line added here
        value += '3'                                     # new line added here

    ...

    if d > 100:
        value += '24'
    else:
        value += '0'
    

    return value
```

My current approach duplicates the code, which means maintaining it in two places. I wondered if it might be possible to structure the code needing the additions in such a way that it could import the original function and make some additional checks before or after it, although this changes the order. Is there a better way of doing this?

The original code is used in a lot of places and providing updates across so many other systems isn't an option - my code will only be using it in one place.

Comment: `a == b == c == d == 1`

Comment: This looks too arbitrary to make any reasonable suggestion.

Comment: Must admit that is a tough one. The problem may be in the general structure of the project

Comment: For your `x == y and x == y and x == y...` section, you could use `match` statements, which should help. https://pastebin.com/Mv62H2Cv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution to this, although it's not a great one. `analyze()` is rewritten to take in an additional argument which links to the `else` statements.

```py
def analyze(result, is_experimental=False):
    a, b, c, d = result
    value = ''
   
    if a > 50:
        value += 'Y'
    elif not is_experimental:
        value += 'N'

    if a == 1 and b == 1 and c == 1 and d == 1:
        value += '1'
    elif a == 2 and b == 1 and c == 1:
        value += 'A'
    elif a == 1 and b == 1 and c == 1:
        value += '2'

    ...

    if d > 100:
        value += '24'
    elif not is_experimental:
        value += '0'
    

    return value
```

This ensures that the code maintains backwards compatibility with anything that currently uses it.

The main part of the code that uses this particular function now needs to parse the output and makes a few substitutions using regex and positional searches. There is likely a better way of doing it but it can now be used in both systems and any updates to the original function should be reflected in the new system.